# Pass Injected EntityManager to a web session persisted object

Tags: java, session, jpa, ejb

Is it secure to pass a Injected EntityManager created on an EJB, to a method that will return an Object, and after, persist that Object on a Web Session for web clients use it?

Like in this example:
the EJB

```
@Stateless(mappedName = "MyService")
@LocalBean
public class MyService implements MyServiceLocal {

@PersistenceContext(unitName="primary")
private EntityManager em;

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public MyService() {   
    }


    @Override
    public Service newServiceX(User user) {
        return new ServiceX(user,em); // here, passing the EntityManager
    }

}
```

After, I persist this Service in a web client (using struts):
The base action

```
    public class YAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware{
    @Inject
    private MyServiceLocal service;

    public String execute(){
    Service x = service.newServiceX();
    persistInCookie("ServiceX",x);
    }

    public void persistInCookie(String, Object){
    // persist
    }
    }
```

And after, using another Action:
// another Action that

```
   class XAction{

   public String useService(){
   getService().doSomething();
   }


   protected Service getService(){
    Service service = (Service) getSessionMap().get("ServiceX");
    return service;
}

}
```

the POJO class ServiceX using the EntityManager:

```
public class ServiceX extends Service{

EntityManager em;

public ServiceX(User user, EntityManager em){
this.em = em;
}

public void doSomething(){
// do something with the EntityManager passed by the EJB
}

}
```

First, the action that would be call is the Y action to persist the Service on the Session, next, the X action will return the Service persisted on the Session and try to use it.

I believe that the EJB Stateless Session Bean can close My EntityManager and this ServiceX POJO class can't use it. This can happen? I found similar question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399769/is-it-okay-to-pass-injected-entitymanagers-to-ejb-beans-helper-classes-and-use), but in this question, the EntityManager is passed to a helper class. In my case is different because I want to persist this Object on a session cookie, and use later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think It is a good idea to store a `EntityManager` in `SessionMap`. What is more, I don't even think that it is a good idea to perform `EntityManager` operations outside the EJB container.

Have read about transaction-boundaries in JPA?

By default, EJB container is using **CMT** (Container Managed Transactions). In this case, container uses **entitymanager-per-request pattern** which means that the transaction begins and ends when one of the business methods of `MyService` starts and ends (transaction is committed or rollbacked in case of RuntimeException). For whole transaction time, `EntityManager` is connected with the same PersistenceContext. After the transaction is ended the container closes `EntityManager` which means that the `EntityManager` is disconnected with recent PersistenceContext:

```
// transaction begins
Service x = service.newServiceX();
// transaction ends
```

This might be crucial if you were going to do some update/insert operations outside the transaction.

Now, when you call `EntityManager` operation (like `find`) outside the transaction, for every each operation the `EntityManager` will create new PersistentContext. This may cause some issues, as two entities that represent the same record will be treated as different entities:

```
// each operation occurs in a separate persistence context, and returns 
// a new detached instance
Magazine mag1 = em.find(Magazine.class, magId);
Magazine mag2 = em.find(Magazine.class, magId);
assertTrue(mag2 != mag1);
```

Some more articles to read:

[Persistent Context](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_overview_emfactory_perscontext.html)

[Transactions and Concurrency](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/transactions.html)

[Entity Lifecycle Management](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_overview_em_lifecycle.html)